# Expand programmatically unwrongest accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to expand programmatically an accordion menu based on saved values in local-storage.
The problem is that it saves the values, i get back the values, but it's not expanding the active ones.
I use the following accordion library:

```
    (function(jQuery){
     jQuery.fn.extend({  
         accordion: function() {       
            return this.each(function() {

                var $ul = $(this);

                if($ul.data('accordiated'))
                    return false;

                $.each($ul.find('ul, li>div'), function(){
                    $(this).data('accordiated', true);
                    $(this).hide();
                });

                $.each($ul.find('a'), function(){
                    $(this).click(function(e){
                        activate(this);
                        return void(0);
                    });
                });

                var active = (location.hash)?$(this).find('a[href=' + location.hash + ']')[0]:'';

                if(active){
                    activate(active, 'toggle');
                    $(active).parents().show();
                }

                function activate(el,effect){
                    $(el).parent('li').toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active').children('ul, div').slideUp('fast');
                    $(el).siblings('ul, div')[(effect || 'slideToggle')]((!effect)?'fast':null);
                }

            });
        } 
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

My HTML (i generate the menu from C#) + JS: Init that gets the menus/submenus that i clicked earlier (but not expanding them :o(   ):

```
    <!--MENU-->
<div id="pageWrap" class="pageWrap">
    <div class="pageContent">
        <ul class="accordion">
            <div id="menucontent">
                <li id="top1"><a href="#">ACCESORII</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid11"><a href="#">ACCESORII PENTRU LANTERNE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub111"><a href='category.aspx?id=72'>accesorii pentru lanterne portabile</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub112"><a href='category.aspx?id=77'>accesorii pentru lanterne industriale reincarcabile</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid12"><a href="#">BECURI DE REZERVA</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub121"><a href='category.aspx?id=67'>becuri de rezerva ambalate individual</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid13"><a href="#">PENTRU CALATORII</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub131"><a href='category.aspx?id=75'>accesorii pentru calatorii</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid14"><a href="#">PENTRU CALCULATOARE, JOCURI SI MUZICA</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub141"><a href='category.aspx?id=79'>pentru calculatoare, jocuri si muzica</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="top2"><a href="#">ACUMULATORI</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid21"><a href="#">ACUMULATORI CU TEHNOLOGIA maxE (fara auto-descarcare)</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub211"><a href='category.aspx?id=80'>MARIMEA R3 (AAA)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub212"><a href='category.aspx?id=81'>MARIMEA R6 (AA)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub213"><a href='category.aspx?id=82'>MARIMEA R14 (C)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub214"><a href='category.aspx?id=83'>MARIMEA R20 (D)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub215"><a href='category.aspx?id=84'>ACUMULATORI DE 9V</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid22"><a href="#">ACUMULATORI NiMH</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub221"><a href='category.aspx?id=12'>ACUMULATORI MARIMEA R3 (Micro AAA)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub222"><a href='category.aspx?id=13'>ACUMULATORI MARIMEA R6 (Mignon AA)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub223"><a href='category.aspx?id=14'>ACUMULATORI MARIMEA R14 (Baby C)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub224"><a href='category.aspx?id=15'>ACUMULATORI MARIMEA R20 (Mono D)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub225"><a href='category.aspx?id=16'>ACUMULATORI MARIMEA 9V</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid23"><a href="#">ACUMULATORI PENTRU TELEFOANE DECT</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub231"><a href='category.aspx?id=85'>Marimea R3 (AAA)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub232"><a href='category.aspx?id=86'>Marimea R6 (AA)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid24"><a href="#">AUMULATORI Ni-Zn</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub241"><a href='category.aspx?id=96'>ACUMULATORI Ni-Zn</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid25"><a href="#">EXTERN</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub251"><a href='category.aspx?id=89'>PowerBank</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid26"><a href="#">HyCell</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub261"><a href='category.aspx?id=91'>HyCell</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid27"><a href="#">PLUMB-GEL RITAR</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub271"><a href='category.aspx?id=98'>ACUMULATOR PLUMB-GEL RITAR</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="top3"><a href="#">BABYCARE</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid31"><a href="#">ALARME BEBELUSI (BABYPHONE)</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub311"><a href='category.aspx?id=54'>BABYPHONE</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid32"><a href="#">LAMPI DE VEGHE SI LAMPI IN FORMA DE JUCARII</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub321"><a href='category.aspx?id=55'>lampi de veghe si lampi in forma de jucarii</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="top4"><a href="#">BATERII</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid41"><a href="#">BATERII ALCALINE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub411"><a href='category.aspx?id=4'>• BATERII RED LINE</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub412"><a href='category.aspx?id=5'>• BATERII X-POWER</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid42"><a href="#">BATERII BUTON</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub421"><a href='category.aspx?id=6'>• BATERII BUTON ALCALINE</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub422"><a href='category.aspx?id=7'>• BATERII BUTON LITIU</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub423"><a href='category.aspx?id=8'>• BATERII AUDITIVE ZINC AIR</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub424"><a href='category.aspx?id=92'>SET BATERII BUTON HyCell</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid43"><a href="#">BATERII LITIU DE                 MARIMI STANDARD</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub431"><a href='category.aspx?id=58'>• BATERII LITIU in blistere</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid44"><a href="#">BATERII LITIU PHOTO</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub441"><a href='category.aspx?id=59'>• BATERI LITIU pentru aplicatii foto</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid45"><a href="#">BATERII SILVER OXID</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub451"><a href='category.aspx?id=93'>BATERII BUTON SILVER OXID</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid46"><a href="#">TESTERE BATERII SI ACCESORII</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub461"><a href='category.aspx?id=9'>• TESTERE BATERII SI ACUMULATORI</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="top5"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid51"><a href="#">GAMA HyCell</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub511"><a href='category.aspx?id=90'>HyCell</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid52"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE CU ACUMULATORI</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub521"><a href='category.aspx?id=42'>INCARCATOARE CU ACUMULATORI</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid53"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE CU MICROPROCESOR</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub531"><a href='category.aspx?id=44'>SERIA POWERLINE</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid54"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE FARA ACUMULATORI</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub541"><a href='category.aspx?id=94'>INCARCATORI FARA ACUMULATOR</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid55"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE HIGH-TECH CU FUNCTIE DE REIMPROSPATARE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub551"><a href='category.aspx?id=45'>seria Energy</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid56"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE MULTIMEDIA</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub561"><a href='category.aspx?id=48'>incarcator pentru acumulatori Lithiu-Ion</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid57"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE Ni-Zn</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub571"><a href='category.aspx?id=97'>INCARCATOARE Ni-Zn</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid58"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE PENTRU ACUMULATORI PB-GEL SI ACUMULATORI AUTO</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub581"><a href='category.aspx?id=49'>incarcatoare pentru baterii cu plumb cu incarcare dupa curba caracteristica IU</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub582"><a href='category.aspx?id=50'>incarcatoare pentru baterii cu plumb cu incarcare dupa curba caracteristica IUoU</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub583"><a href='category.aspx?id=51'>incarcatoare pentru baterii auto cu plumb sau plumb-gel</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid59"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE RAPIDE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub591"><a href='category.aspx?id=47'>cu microprocesor pentru pachete de acumlatori</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid510"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE STANDARD</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub5101"><a href='category.aspx?id=41'>BASIC</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub5102"><a href='category.aspx?id=46'>pentru acumulatori NiCd/NiMH</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid511"><a href="#">INCARCATOARE ULTRARAPIDE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub5111"><a href='category.aspx?id=43'>ULTRARAPIDE</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid512"><a href="#">SERIA GLOBAL LINE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub5121"><a href='category.aspx?id=60'>seria Global line</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid513"><a href="#">SURSE DE ALIMENTARE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub5131"><a href='category.aspx?id=52'>surse de alimentare universale</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="top6"><a href="#">LANTERNE</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid61"><a href="#">INDICATOR</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub611"><a href='category.aspx?id=71'>indicator cu lanterna</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid62"><a href="#">LANTERNE ANTI-EX</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub621"><a href='category.aspx?id=61'>lanterne industriale reincarcabile</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid63"><a href="#">LANTERNE CU CARCASA METALICA</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub631"><a href='category.aspx?id=63'>cu carcasa metalica</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid64"><a href="#">LANTERNE DE FRUNTE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub641"><a href='category.aspx?id=57'>lanterne de frunte</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid65"><a href="#">LANTERNE DE LUCRU</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub651"><a href='category.aspx?id=95'>LANTERNE DE LUCRU</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid66"><a href="#">LANTERNE HOME DECORATION</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub661"><a href='category.aspx?id=69'>lanterne Lifestyle</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid67"><a href="#">LANTERNE INDUSTRIALE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub671"><a href='category.aspx?id=78'>lanterne industriale reincarcabile</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid68"><a href="#">LANTERNE LASER</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub681"><a href='category.aspx?id=70'>lanterne laser (Laserpointer)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid69"><a href="#">LANTERNE PORTABILE REINCARCABILE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub691"><a href='category.aspx?id=65'>lanterne portabile reincarcabile (AS, ASN)</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid610"><a href="#">LANTERNE REINCARCABILE</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub6101"><a href='category.aspx?id=66'>lanterne reincarcabile</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid611"><a href="#">LANTERNE SERIA AGENT</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub6111"><a href='category.aspx?id=56'>seria AGENT</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid612"><a href="#">LANTERNE TIP BRELOC</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub6121"><a href='category.aspx?id=64'>tip breloc</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="top7"><a href="#">TEHNOLOGIA ZERO WATT</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="mid71"><a href="#">PRIZE ECOMOMICE ZERO WATT</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li id="sub711"><a href='category.aspx?id=53'>seria AES</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.accordion.source.js"></script>
<script>
    // <![CDATA[

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('ul').accordion();
        });

        // ]]>
</script>
<script>
    /*Main Left Menu Begin*/
        var topActiveid = "";
        var level1Activeid = "";
        var level2Activeid = "";

        $(document).ready(function() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("activeLeftMenu") != null)
        {
            var strarray = localStorage.getItem("activeLeftMenu").split("/");
            topActiveid = strarray[0].toString();
            level1Activeid = strarray[1].toString();
            level2Activeid = strarray[2].toString();

            $(".accordion>ul>li.active").removeClass("active");
            //if ($("#"+topActiveid) =! null)
                $("#"+topActiveid).addClass('active');
                $("#"+topActiveid).click();
                $("#"+topActiveid).slideDown();
            //if ($("#"+level1Activeid) =! null)
                $("#"+level1Activeid).addClass('active');
                $("#"+level1Activeid).click();
                $("#"+level1Activeid).slideDown();
            //if ($("#"+level2Activeid) =! null)
                $("#"+level2Activeid).addClass('active');//$('#topx3').addClass('active'): 
                $("#"+level2Activeid).click();
                $("#"+level2Activeid).slideDown();
                 // $('#menu li.active').show();
                //  $('#menu li.active').slideDown('normal');
        }
        });
</script>
<!--MENU-->
```

I tried to use click() , slidedown() , show() to expand, but none of them are working. It's just selecting the top level, without expanding (see screenshot / i also attached the link).

img: [Not expanding menu - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cggbS.jpg)

link: [Website](https://www.sawexim.ro/)

Comment: This would really boost your chances of getting to the bottom of the issue (and others taking a closer look) => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem (i think) is in the /*Main Left Menu Begin*/ JS section after removing and adding class ('active'). In this section i read out the value from localStorage, i split it and i'm adding the class 'active' to the items.
After that i would like to expand somehow the top, level1, level2 menu. I tried with click(), slideDown(), show(), but non of them are working. I can't tell the exact line number that is causing the problem. I tried in FF debug to expand from Watch Variables, but its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the .click() on the *a* element which handles the click.

Then it is working fine.

Eg.

```
$('#top6 > a').click()
```

Or in your code:

```
$("#"+topActiveid + " > a").click();
```

The logic to add / remove the *active* class and also the slidedown() call are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick help. Awesome, it worked flawless.